# NextJS GetServerSideProps typing issues

Tags: typescript, next.js

Hi as the title suggests, I am having issues with the GSSR typings.
I am not sure what I need to do and due to the nature of the work am unable to make a codepen. Thanks.

"next": "12.1.0",
"typescript": "4.5.5"

[image]

Comment: You're simply missing the `async` keyword on the `getServerSideProps` function declaration, i.e. `export const getserverSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {`.